# What is the best way to create a custom toast from scratch?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view, android-toast

I want create my own toast from scratch. **It means I don't want to use the android `Toast` class in any aspect.** My toast will be implement in MainActivity and invoke by EventBus from any place in application. In my application I've only one activity (MainActivity) and many fragments as a screens. In my toast I want to implement the similar functionality as in android Toast (e.g. hide after 3 seconds, create queue when many toast appears in the same moments etc.), but I don't want to use the android `Toast` class.

I wonder what is the best way to do a custom toast? Create Fragment? View? Any other ideas?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you not using [library](https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty).

Comment: @AndroidPlayer_Shree Toasty library use android Toast inside.

Answer (score 0):

`customt_toast.xml`

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootId"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In your view:

```
View toastLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, 
                   (R.id.rootId));

TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("blah blah");

Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(toastLayout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: I don't want to customize view. I want to create `Toast` class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you can create a custom toast like green background with success toast or red background with error toast. Just follow the instructions step by step:

1. First copy and paste given two functions in a kotlin file outside of class declaration so that you can access from anywhere in your project.

   ```
   fun showErrorToast(context: Context, message: String) {
       val parent: ViewGroup? = null
       val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
       val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
       val toastView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_error, parent)
       toastView.errorMessage.text = message
       toast.view = toastView
       toast.show()
   }

   fun showSuccessToast(context: Context, message: String) {
       val parent: ViewGroup? = null
       val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
       val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
       val toastView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_success, parent)
       toastView.successMessage.text = message
       toast.view = toastView
       toast.show()
   }
   ```
2. Then create two xml layout file named "toast_custom_error" and "toast_custom_success", then copy and paste these two xml layout code to these files.

   "toast_custom_error"

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/container"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg_error"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
               android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   "toast_custom_success"

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/container"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg_success"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
               android:id="@+id/successMessage"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Then create two drawable xml file named "rounded_bg_error" and "rounded_bg_success" and paste below codes into them:

   "rounded_bg_error"

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
       <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
       <solid android:color="#F81616" />
   </shape>
   ```

   "rounded_bg_success"

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
       <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
       <solid android:color="#B2FF59" />
   </shape>
   ```
4. Finally call the above two functions from anywhere in your project as your need like:

From fragment-->

```
    showErrorToast(requireContext(), "Your Error Message")
    showSuccessToast(requireContext(), "Your Success Message")
```

From activity-->

```
    showErrorToast(this, "Your Error Message")
    showSuccessToast(this, "Your Success Message")
```

Comment: I want to create my own implementation of `Toast` class, not use android `Toast`.

Comment: @wapn Then you should create a class that extends Toast class and customize the properties by overriding Toast class'es properties.

Comment: No, I want to get rid of android `Toast` class completly.

Comment: @wapn ok then you create a dialog fragment and show it as non cancellable so that user can not dismiss it and run a kotlin coroutine runbloking code with expected timing inside the onViewCreated() function and call dismiss() function after the delay call and it will dismiss. This is the updated way of doing so without custom toast. You will find no other efficient way of doing what you want so far I know brother.

Comment: No additional code needed، This library makes your job easier
https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty