# Android: how to display a custom toast from a context received from onPushReceive()?

Tags: android, kotlin

My app contains an `Application` object at top-level, which itself contains an AppCompatActivity:

**Application.kt**

```
class Application : android.app.Application() {
    // ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".Application" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
    />
</application>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // ...
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Now when I get a notification, I want to display a custom toast like explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767409/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-custom-toast-from-scratch). My problem is that I don't know what to do with this line:

```
View toastLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (R.id.rootId))
```

Because I can't access the layoutInflater, or I don't know how to. When I check `context` or `context.applicationContext`, I get my `Application` object, but then I don't have the ability to access `findViewById()`.

**Watcher**

```
class Watcher : ParsePushBroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onPushReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        // how to access layoutInflater here, or whatever needed to display a custom layout?
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `getLayoutInflater()` instead of that add `context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater`

Try the below code

```
class Watcher : ParsePushBroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val message = intent.getStringExtra("message")

    val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, null)

    val textView = layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toast_text)
    textView.text = message

    val toast = Toast(context)
    toast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    toast.view = layout
    toast.show()
}}
```